# Hadoop Administration

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, administration

I setup a Hadoop 1.2.x version, Two node Cluster. First Node (NameNode, Jobtracker) and Second Node (Secondary NameNode, Datanode, TaskTracker).

How do I Set the map and reduce slots to 4 and 2 respectively for each node
and How do I verify the same from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `slots` per tasktracker node, limit the maximum number of tasks a node can run simultaneously.

Add these properties to `mapred-site.xml`

```
<property>
   <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
   <value>4</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
   <value>2</value>
</property>
```

You can check the configurations used by `jobtracker` using

```
hadoop jobtracker -dumpConfiguration
```

Comment: Thank You franklinsijo. Thank You very much.